# Error: 'import[\s\S]*from\s+'react-navigation';?' was not found in file E:\ myProjects\myProject/App/Navigation/AppNavigation.js

Tags: react-native

i am using Ignite 2.0.0 , and today started facing this issue, whenever i am running

> ignite generate container MypageName

its throwing the following error

Error: 'import[\s\S]*from\s+'react-navigation';?' was not found in file E:\ App/Navigation/AppNavigation.js.

and therefore it is not adding the container I generated to AppNavigation.js file. 
Two days back it was working perfect.